# Split XML into multiple files using xslt on string length

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm looking at trying to split an XML file into 2 separate files.  They have to be split on the length of a string in a particular element.

I've been attempting to use the `<xsl:for-each-group>` and `<xsl:result-document>` elements in order to do this but only get the 1st matching 'object' in the result file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <bookId>4125151</bookId>
        <author>John Davies</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <bookId>1000257896</bookId>
    <author>Lee Frost</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <bookId>1234569870</bookId>
        <author>Joe Walters</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <bookId>2145789</bookId>
        <author>Sarah Wyer</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <bookId>4085151</bookId>
        <author>Jane Cohen</author>
    </book>
</books>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="books">
 <xsl:for-each-group select="book[string-length(bookId)!=10]" group-by="string-length(book/bookId)">

    <xsl:result-document href="file:/C:/devFiles/legacy.xml">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:result-document>

    </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result should be the books by John Davies, Joe Walters, Sarah Wyer and Jane Cohen all being saved in *legacy.xml*

Am I on the right track?  Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would the book by Lee Frost not be in the same group as the one by Joe Walters? Both have a `bookId` of 10 characters. -- Also, you speak of multiple files: what would be the name/s of the other file/s and what would be included in it/them?

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  Joe Walters should be in the other file with Lee Frost - in the other file.

As for the 'multiple' files, in this instance I only need the 2 files. legacy.xml (bookIds not 10 in length) & current.xml (bookIds with length of 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only need the 2 files. legacy.xml (bookIds not 10 in length) &
>   current.xml (bookIds with length of 10).

Then I would suggest you do it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/books">
    <books>
        <xsl:copy-of select="book[string-length(bookId)=10]" />
    </books>
    <xsl:result-document href="file:/C:/devFiles/legacy.xml">
        <books>
            <xsl:copy-of select="book[string-length(bookId)!=10]" />
        </books>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will return the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
   <book>
        <bookId>1000257896</bookId>
      <author>Lee Frost</author>
    </book>
   <book>
        <bookId>1234569870</bookId>
        <author>Joe Walters</author>
    </book>
</books>
```

as the "normal" result of the transformation, which you can direct to a file when initiating the transformation, and also create the `legacy.xml` file containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
   <book>
        <bookId>4125151</bookId>
        <author>John Davies</author>
    </book>
   <book>
        <bookId>2145789</bookId>
        <author>Sarah Wyer</author>
    </book>
   <book>
        <bookId>4085151</bookId>
        <author>Jane Cohen</author>
    </book>
</books>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems the simplest solution.  potame's solution from the other day also worked - I was just being an idiot looking in the wrong folder for the resultant file!